# I get ImportError: libpng16.so.16 only in virtualenv (ubuntu 14.04, python 2.7.6)

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, virtualenv

While using matplotlib.pyplot in python interpreter in virtual environment I get this error :

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as a

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/haz/Envs/DataVizProj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 29, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/home/haz/Envs/DataVizProj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 34, in <module>
    import matplotlib.collections as collections
  File "/home/haz/Envs/DataVizProj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
  File "/home/haz/Envs/DataVizProj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 62, in <module>
    import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
  File "/home/haz/Envs/DataVizProj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 18, in <module>
    from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
  File "/home/haz/Envs/DataVizProj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 60, in <module>
    import matplotlib._png as _png
ImportError: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have already installed **ZLIB , FREETYPE , LIBPNG** for matplotlib and I
only get this error in virtualenv.I am a beginner and following this [tutorial](http://newcoder.io/dataviz/part-1/).
Btw I don't use anaconda or canopy .Just python2.7

Comment: try this : install a old version "libpng". You haven't installed(latest version got some error).

Comment: How did you install mpl?

Comment: I got it by using pip